# About mongodb database transaction

Tags: java, mongodb

Java for mongodb database operations, the problem is how to solve it matters? I hope there is a specific implementation steps.

Answer (score 0):

When you choose NoSQL, you give up ACID.

If you want transactions, go to a relational database that supports them.

Comment: Some NoSQL databses provide ACID characteristics. And Mongo itself does provide limited support (at the document level). But for a complex transaction scheme, I agree that Mongo is probably not the right solution.

Comment: I agree with @assylias To say you give up ACID in all senses is wrong, MongoDB may not have complex transactions ranging over separate tables however it does have single document transactions and atomicity which means that it does apply it own required form of transactions but yes, again, not in the way the OP is looking for

Comment: That Mongodb database what can you do? In case the project fails to update the data how to do it?